# How to create constructors within a class where one of the fields is an array(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I'm trying to create a class that constructs a football team object but I'm not quite sure how arrays actually work as fields. My constructor looks like this:

```
public class FootballTeam {
private String[] players;
private String colour;
private int goalDifference;
private Boolean challengeTrophy;

//---------- Construction and Initialisation of the FootballTeam object---------- //
public FootballTeam(String[] aPlayer, String aColour, int aGoalDifference, Boolean inChallengeTrophy) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {players[i] = aPlayer[i]}
    colour = aColour;
    goalDifference = aGoalDifference;
    challengeTrophy = inChallengeTrophy;
}
```

I'm really not sure about how to go about writing the constructor so that I can just use an array of strings to test the players part.

I also have to create methods that allow for a new player to be added or removed and I'm not sure how I'd structure that, any help would be greatly appreciated; cheers!

Comment: Why not simply `players = aPlayer`? Both are Arrays of type String so you can just assign them without a for-loop

Answer (score 3):

You can just:

```
this.players = aPlayer;
```

If you want to copy array content (as you are doing in for loop), you need to initialize players first.

```
 this.players = new String[numberOfFields];
```

Comment: **note** that the `this` is optional in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what are you trying to do with your String array but if you really want to do that you have to initialise your array like this :

```
public FootballTeam(String[] aPlayer, String aColour, int aGoalDifference, Boolean inChallengeTrophy) {
    players = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        players[i] = aPlayer[i];
    }
    colour = aColour;
    goalDifference = aGoalDifference;
    challengeTrophy = inChallengeTrophy;
}
```

But if you want store your aPlayer in your object you can just :

```
public FootballTeam(String[] aPlayer, String aColour, int aGoalDifference, Boolean inChallengeTrophy) {
    players = aPlayer;
    colour = aColour;
    goalDifference = aGoalDifference;
    challengeTrophy = inChallengeTrophy;
}
```

Be careful with this because if you modify one element of players it will also modify aPlayer because you just copy references instead of deep copy of each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You did it right. But instead of using a for loop to make both arrays the same you could just put "players = aPlayer;".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class FootballTeam {
    private Set<String> players;
    private String colour;
    private int goalDifference;
    private Boolean challengeTrophy;

    public FootballTeam(String[] aPlayer, String aColour, int aGoalDifference, Boolean inChallengeTrophy) {
        players = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(aPlayer));
        colour = aColour;
        goalDifference = aGoalDifference;
        challengeTrophy = inChallengeTrophy;
    }

    public void addPlayer(String player) {
        players.add(player);
    }

    public void removePlayer(String player) {
        players.remove(player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the entire for loop part with this line

```
this.players = Arrays.copyOfRange(aPlayer,0,5)
```

Avoid direct assignment as that's scary because the same reference is repeated in every object. Besides copyofrange also allows you to add first 5 players etc. according to the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to do a simple assignation `this.players = aPlayer` because if your aPlayer content change the players array will be updated too.

To do a copy you can do a loop but it may be better to use `System.arraycopy` or `Arrays.copyOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code with you constructor.

**Sample Code**

```
public FootballTeam(String[] aPlayer, String aColour, int aGoalDifference, Boolean inChallengeTrophy) {
    players = new String[aPlayer.length];
    players = aPlayer;
    colour = aColour;
    goalDifference = aGoalDifference;
    challengeTrophy = inChallengeTrophy;
}
```

Here first you need to `initialize` size of `array` than you can `initialize` entire `array` value.

Hope it will help you easily.